# O que é $parent em AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Estou revisando um PR de um colega e me deparei com o uso de `$parent`, li um pouco na documentação do angular, porém não consigo entender o que ele faz. 
Ele é usado dentro de um dialog criado dentro de outro, isso teria alguma relação por ter como `keyword` a palavra `parent`?
Seguem minhas dúvidas sobre seu uso.

- Em termos leigos, o que `$parent` faz?
- Qual a ocasião onde é necessário o uso de `$parent`
- Porque ele é usado já que ambos dialog's dividem o controller, seus scopes não deveriam ser os mesmos já?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$parent` é uma maneira de acessar dados de escopos anteriores na hierarquia a partir de escopos isolados.

Exemplo:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.dados = "dados!";
})
.directive("dirScope", function () { 
  return { scope: true, template: '<div>dirScope: {{dados}}</div>'};
})
.directive("dirNoScope", function () {
  return { scope: {}, template: '<div>dirNoScope: {{dados}}</div>'};
})
.directive("dirNoScopeParent", function () {
  return { scope: {}, template: '<div>dirNoScopeParent: {{$parent.dados}}</div>' };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
  {{dados}}
  
  <dir-scope></dir-scope>
  <dir-no-scope></dir-no-scope>
  <dir-no-scope-parent></dir-no-scope-parent>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Ao clicar em <kbd>Executar</kbd> você irá perceber que as diretivas `dirScope` e `dirNoScopeParent` corretamente exibem o valor de `dados` - porém `dirNoScope` não.

`dirScope` é capaz porque seu escopo é compartilhado com o elemento-pai, via definição `scope: true`.

`dirNoScope`, por sua vez, tem seu escopo isolado - `scope: {}` - e, por isso, não herda do escopo-pai.

`dirNoScopeParent` também tem seu escopo isolado por `scope: {}`. Entretando, o valor de `dados` consegue ser propriamente lido porque `$parent` é usado na definição do template, escapando da limitação do escopo e alcançando assim o valor desejado.